# How to find the shortest path between two blobs(contours/closed curves) using MATLAB?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing

`bwlabel` can be used to get disconnected objects in an image:

```
[L Ne] = bwlabel(image);
```

How to calculate the shortest path between two disconnected closed curves?

Is there a practical(not theoretical) solution?

Comment: Can you clarify?  Do you want to connect two arbitrary disconnected objects, or do you want to connect all objects to form one object?

If the latter, are you looking for the set of connections that minimizes the total path length of those connections?  If so, that's the travelling salesman problem; search for that.

Comment: It's the latter,but not exactly,salesman problem is for finding shortest path between isolated **points**,but here it's to find the shortest path between **contours** /polygons.

Comment: Have you tried bwmorph? It has operations like dilation and erosion including one called close that does dilation then erosion in one.

Comment: I've taken a look at `bwmorph`, it doesn't have the feature to make unconnected objects connected

Comment: @user198729: it's still exactly the same problem.  The distance between each set of two objects is some number;  you want to find a way to connect the contours s.t. you minimize the sum of those numbers.  The fact that that number differs from the distance between the centers of mass doesn't change the algorithm you would use.

Is your question really how to find the distance between two blobs instead of between two point particles?

Comment: Yes,my question is about two blobs,or contours to be exact.I don't think it's quite the same thing,you'll have to calculate all distances between each objects,and how?

Comment: how many pixels in the contour of each blob?

Answer (score 1):

#### Suggestion 1

Try extracting the coordinates of the perimeter pixels of the objects you want to connect and use them as nodes in your graph. Then use the [A* algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*) to find the shortest paths between each pair between your sets. This effectively solves the all-pairs problem using A* but restricting it to nodes of interest (paths from nodes in one object to the other).

#### Suggestion 2 (simpler)

Another idea (untested) is to compute the shortest path between the centroid of each blob (regionprops can be used to compute the centroid) and see which perimeter pixel is intersected by the path. Of course, this might work if your centroid is within the blob, but things get messy with non-convex blobs. This reduces the complexity of your algorithm to the number of blobs as opposed to the number of perimeter pixels (which can be huge).

Also, if **Suggestion 2** works for you, you can use [Floyd-Warshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) to compute the shortest paths between all the blobs in the image.

Comment: Maybe I'm complicating the problem. Could you post an image? I'd like to see what you mean by "shortest path".

Comment: You can use the contour of MATLAB's built-in image `coins.png`,basically several disconnected circles.

Comment: Do you need to compute the shortest paths between all objects or just two?

Comment: @Jacob ,I've simplified my question,is there a practical solution?

Comment: How to get the contures by `bwlabel` and iterate over each point between different contures?