# Cluster growing of blobs

Tags: performance, matlab, image-processing, shortest-path

Consider the following image which is from Mathworks:

[image]

I have labelled the blobs with

```
 [L, num]= bwlabel(I);
```

How do I connect all the blobs iteratively,i.e.start with one blob and find the nearest one to it.Consider the left-most two blobs, there can be many lines that can be drawn from many points of a blob to connect to the other blob, but the shortest one would be obtained by finding the pixel of a blob that is nearest to the other blob, find a similar pixel in the other blob and connect these two pixels.I would like connect them in this manner.After connecting them, which makes them a single blob, find the blob closest to this new blob connect them, and so on, until all the whole image has a single closed structure? Also, the blobs aren't always circular,they are of random shapes.

Similar questions have been asked here:

[How to find the shortest path between two blobs(contours/closed curves) using MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653511/how-to-find-the-shortest-path-between-two-blobscontours-closed-curves-using-ma)
and
http://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/270149

Using bwdist(), I could separate two blobs and use brute force approach to find the shortest distance by testing on all pairs of pixels in the two blobs as mentioned in the second link but it takes a really long time.Is there a better way to approach this so that the results can be obtained faster?

**Edit:**

This is another image:

[image]

Required image:

[image]

Comment: Shortest distance between two blobs for all the blobs? So with 4 blobs, you would have 6 distances ,considering them in pairs? Also would the shortest distances be measured between the contour points or the centroid points of the blobs?

Comment: Are the blobs always circular?

Comment: @Divakar No, I would like to connect it as a sequence, i.e. Blob 1 to blob 2, then blob 2 to blob 3 and so on until the last blob.

Comment: @ Rose Gronchi No, they aren't always circular.

Comment: If you are only trying to *connect* blobs, we can use just use the centroid points and find the shortest distances between them. But if you are interested in finding the *distances*, you need to specify if the distances are measured between their centroid points or for all contour points in one  blob against the contour points for all other blobs and finding the minimum from them. So, please clarify - 1) Is it connecting blobs or finding the shortest distances. 2) If its about distance calculation, how are they to be measured (between contour or centroid points)?

Comment: I would like to connect the blobs.In the image above, if we consider the left-most two blobs, there can be many lines that can be drawn from many points of a blob to connect to the other blob, but the shortest one would be obtained by finding the pixel of a blob that is nearest to the other blob, find a similar pixel in the other blob and connect these two pixels.I would like connect them in this manner.

Comment: @Divakar By using the centroid points, if the shortest distance is obtained,                                             will I get the same result as the one I have mentioned in my above comment?

Comment: By the "shortest" distance, could we simply look at the perimeter of the objects?  Intuitively, the shortest distance between any two blobs would lie along the perimeter of the objects.  BTW this problem is quite unconstrained.  It would help you if you provided an example of what would be classified as two blobs connecting together.  You probably won't get any answers until you edit your question to have at least this.

Comment: @rayryeng Yes, that is right.Can you please suggest any steps for this?

Comment: @Matt - So would you go through each blob and determine which blob is the closest to the one in question?  In other words, if we have `N` blobs, for each blob 1, 2, 3, up to `N`, do we determine which blob is the closest?

Comment: Also, define what you mean by "slow".  Do you have an image where the algorithms you have tried are slow?  We can reduce the complexity of this problem considerably by only looking at pixels that lie along the perimeter of the blobs.

Comment: Yes, I want to choose a blob arbitrarily and check which blob is closest to it and connect them.Now, the two blobs will be a single blob.The repeat again, until there is only a single blob.

Comment: You are pretty much describing agglomerative / hierarchical clustering: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering#Example_for_Agglomerative_Clustering - Except that you are dealing with a more unconstrained problem.  You aren't considering single points.  You are considering clusters of points.

Comment: Using bwdist(), the distance of each pixel of first blob to the ones in second blob should be computed to get the shortest distance.I had tried bwdist() recently in another piece of code and Matlab froze several times when I tried to stop running the code.So I want to know if there is any better way.

Comment: Yes, you have described it perfectly!

Comment: Yeah, I would avoid using `bwdist` first off and only consider using the perimeter of each blob.  I'm also in the process of working on something.  Give me a moment.... however, you are pretty much trying to implement an agglomerative clustering.  Find two blobs that are closest to each other, connect them together so they form a group, then find two more blobs, connect them together so they form a group, and you keep repeating this until you get a single group.  One of the most classical techniques for unsupervised data mining and machine learning.

Comment: @Matt - This actually will be simpler with the centroids.  You will certainly get the same result you're looking for if we consider just the centroids.  Give me a few more minutes

Comment: Ok I'll also try to see if I can work it out :)

Comment: I'm about to go to bed, but I have written something.  It's not perfect, but it leverages computational complexity for accuracy.  If no one has written a response until the time I wake up, I'll post something.  Stay tuned.

Comment: Ok good night! Please do give me some pointers on this after you wake up.I am unable to come up with anything and the deadline for my project is drawing near

Comment: By "connect", is it okay to do so with single-width line or does the "connection" has to be a thick pipe-like structure between two blobs?

Comment: A single-width line is sufficient :)

Comment: Would something like [this](http://postimg.org/image/63uggesqr/) work? Look at how the "connections" are made and see if this is what you were after.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think so.I want to connect it as a sequence, first blob to second, second to third and so on.I guess I hadn't written the question clearly.I have edited the question, please do see it again

Comment: How this [one](http://postimg.org/image/cu7oal5mz/) ?

Comment: Yes, I think that might be it.Could you tell me how you obtained that image?

Comment: Could you draw the expected output for the *Edit*ed images. As in how would like those " curved lines" to be "connected". Post the expected output image here? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I will post it now

Comment: I am very sorry if my question was confusing.I did not know how to explain.

Comment: @Matt Well, it would be really computationally heavy though, because with that case, you need to use the boundary points for each blob, rather than the centroids.

Comment: Oh, is there no function or some simple steps to find the boundary points of a blob?

Comment: @Matt Look into `bwboundaries`.

Comment: Yes, I have used that function but does it give end points?

Comment: For that you can follow the [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28323143/3293881) on how to use it, for some guidance. It gets the boundary points in  a cell array. So, you need to get them into numeric arrays.

Comment: Ok thank you :) I have edited the question to include another figure.Please give me an idea on how to perform that

Comment: The image needs to be closed at the place where it is not connected.Is it difficult to do this?

Comment: @Matt - Divakar has solved your problem and is a great answer.  It puts my idea to shame!  In any case, I have reworded the title of your post to better reflect what is actually being done here.  Connected Components of Labels doesn't seem to represent what is truly going on here.  Good luck!

Comment: @rayryeng Thank you very much :) I am sure your idea was good too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Approach #1 : Connecting with the centroid points

```
%// Read image, convert to binary and remove some whitish border across it
im = im2bw(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUsrl.png'));
BW = im(3:end-2,3:end-2);
figure, imshow(BW), title('Starting/Original Image')

%// Find centroid points for each blob
cpts = reshape(round(struct2array(regionprops(BW,'Centroid'))),2,[])'; %//'

%// Initialize 2 groups- "hungry" & "feeder" groups, naming them as grp1 & grp2
grp1 = []; grp2 = cpts;

%// Initialize the blob index matching IDs
R = 1; C = 1;

while ~isempty(grp2)
    
    %// Get one from Group-2 into Group 1 based on the closest one that was
    %//obtained from the previous iteration. Remove that from Group -2.
    grp1 = [grp1 ; grp2(C,:)];
    grp2(C,:) = [];
    
    %// Find squared distances between those two groups
    sq_distmat = squared_dist(grp1,grp2);
    
    %// Find the IDs minimum one across row and column which would be the
    %IDs for group 1 and 2 respectively, calling them as R and C
    [~,idx] = min(sq_distmat(:));
    [R,C] = ind2sub(size(sq_distmat),idx);
    
    %// Draw the connecting line
    BW = linept(BW, grp1(R,2), grp1(R,1), grp2(C,2), grp2(C,1));
    
end
figure, imshow(BW), title('Final Connected Image')
```

Associated function -

```
function sq_distmat = squared_dist(A,B)

[nA,dim] = size(A);
nB = size(B,1);

A_ext = ones(nA,dim*3);
A_ext(:,2:3:end) = -2*A;
A_ext(:,3:3:end) = A.^2;

B_ext = ones(nB,dim*3);
B_ext(:,1:3:end) = B.^2;
B_ext(:,2:3:end) = B;

sq_distmat = A_ext * B_ext.';

return;
```

Animation fun -

[image]

---

### Approach #2 : Connecting with the contour points

```
%// Read image, convert to binary and remove some whitish border across it
im = im2bw(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUsrl.png'));
BW = im(3:end-2,3:end-2);

%// Find boundary points as a cell array
bpts_cell = bwboundaries(BW);

%// Initialize 2 groups- "hungry" & "feeder" groups, naming them as grp1 & grp2
grp1c = []; grp2c = bpts_cell;

ID = 1;
for iter = 1:numel(bpts_cell)-1
    
    %// Get one from Group-2 into Group 1 based on the closest one that was
    %obtained from the previous iteration. Remove that from Group -2.
    grp1c = [grp1c ; grp2c(ID)];
    grp2c(ID,:) = [];
    grp1 = vertcat(grp1c{:});
    grp2 = vertcat(grp2c{:});
    
    %// Find squared distances between those two groups
    sq_distmat = squared_dist(grp1,grp2);
    
    %// Find the IDs minimum one across row and column which would be the
    %IDs for group 1 and 2 respectively, calling them as R and C
    [~,idx] = min(sq_distmat(:));
    [R,C] = ind2sub(size(sq_distmat),idx);
    
    %// Draw the connecting line
    BW = linept(BW, grp1(R,1), grp1(R,2), grp2(C,1), grp2(C,2));
    
    lens = cellfun('length',grp2c);
    clens = cumsum(lens);    
    ID = find(C<=clens,1);
end
```

Animation fun -

[image]

Animated output with the Edit image -

[image]

Comment: @Matt It should work for any image, but since it uses `centroids`, it might look "tricky" with hugely irregular or concave shaped blobs.

Comment: Could you suggest some steps for such cases? I just used this as a sample image but I have others which have lines and other shapes instead of blobs.

Comment: @Matt As I said, it should be good for such cases as well, just give them a try!

Comment: I did, but the lines are curved and the centroids are not located on the lines and so the output is not right.I will edit my post and include such an image

Comment: @Matt Yes, please post the image you get from it.

Comment: I have added the new images

Comment: @Matt Check out the new approach!

Comment: I used it on a few images and the results are splendid :) Thank you very very much!!